# How to pass specified parameters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, parameters, option-type

I would like to pass value to specified parameters and use default value by optional parameters for the rest.

A sample is made as below.

Current result is 'b23'.

But I would like to obtain the result of '1b3'.

```
function runThis() {
    test(b='b');
}
```

```
function test(a='1',b='2',c='3'){
    console.println(a+b+c);
}
```

I also try to run `test({b:'b'})` and `test({b:='b'})`, resulting SyntaxError.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `console.println` isn't JavaScript. Did you mean `console.log`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is slightly different:

```
> function test({a=1, b=2, c=3}) { console.log(a+b+c); }
undefined
> test({b:"b"})
1b3
undefined
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Tested and it works in google script. But sadly, it is not accepted by Adobe Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters are positional in javascript - the first parameter will always be 'a', the second 'b' and so on.

One way to achieve named parameters would be to change the signature of the function test to accept an object:

```
function test(obj) {
    const { a='1', b='2', c='3' } = obj
    console.log(a + b + c)
}
```

Calling this with

```
test({ b: 'b' })
```

will yield '1b3'

Comment: Thank you for your help and detailed clarification. Tested and it works with google script but not in Adobe Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Keyword arguments are *not* supported in JS, arguments are resolved by their position in JS.

You could instead pass in an object and [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) the properties from it and also assign default values.

```js
function runThis() {
  test({ b: "b" });
}

function test(inputObj) {
  const { a = "1", b = "2", c = "3" } = inputObj;
  console.log(a + b + c);
}

runThis();
```

You could also do the destructuring more succinctly, as shown below:

```
function test({ a = "1", b = "2", c = "3" }) {
  console.log(a + b + c);
}
```

Also, `console.println` is *not* a thing in JS, you can use `console.log` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Just let you know because I tested the code using Adobe Javascript. So I used console.println.